# SAR command in X86 assembly with one parameter

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

In a disassembled program I'm analyzing, I found the command

```
sar %eax
```

What does this do? I know that `sar` with two arguments performs a right shift, but I can't find what it means with only one parameter.

This program was compiled for an Intel x86 processor.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Looks like the dissembler used short-hand for `SAR EAX,1` which has an opcode of `0xD1F8`. when the immediate is not 1, aka `SAR EAX,xx`, the opcode is `0xC1F8 xx`, see the Intel Instruction reference, Vol. 2B, 4-353.

Comment: And you can find the reference manual at http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325383.pdf

Answer (score 7):

When there is only one operand  the implied shift is 1.

So....

`SAR %EAX` implies signed `%EAX >> 1`

therefor,

```
SAR %eax = SAR $1, %eax
```

I have successfully proven this analyzing some code in GDB.

Comment: What part of the other answer is wrong? It says  `used short-hand for SAR EAX,1` . The other answer represented the output as Intel syntax rather than AT&T but the answer seems okay. The x86 has a special short encoding for the 4 shift instructions that can be used with no 2nd operand or you can encode the value 1 as a 2nd operand which is a longer instruction that does the same thing.

Comment: Fortunately `gas` will optimize `sar $1, %eax` into the implicit by-one opcode, so you don't get inefficient code if you write it that way.  And BTW, there are also by-one short forms of `ror`, `rol`, `rcl`, and `rcr`, as well as `shl` (aka `sal`), `shr`, and `sar`.  But not `shrd`, that was added later with only imm8/cl versions.