# Difference between `shl di` and `shl di, 1`

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I tried to compile the following with NASM

```
shl di
```

which, according to [this very non-sketchy source](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html) should multiply `di` by 2 once. However, I get an "invalid combination of opcode and operands" from NASM. After a bit of head-scratching, resolved to using

```
shl di, 1
```

which is magically OK with NASM and everything is OK with me too, except that now I am left with a question because, off the top of my head, I could have sworn that the first form was a thing, but maybe I'm misremembering things.

So, which is it?

Comment: Depends on assembler. Apparently nasm requires the count even if it's 1. It will nevertheless emit the machine code for the implicit version.

Comment: The implicit-count form (in the asm source) is a thing in GAS.  For example in AT&T syntax: [SAR command in X86 assembly with one parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12813962) is the opposite question from this, people puzzled by the one-operand form.  (GAS does still assemble `shr $1, %di` into the implicit-count form, not an immediate count of 1).  As @old_timer loves to say, assembly language (source text) depends on the tool, not just the machine code / ISA.

Comment: Anyway, as always you should look at how your assembler (NASM) assembles them to machine code.  It's the same bytes, so there's literally zero difference in what the CPU executes.

Comment: I had noticed that the bytes produced were those I expected, hence the confusion. Thanks of clarifying.

Comment: Near duplicate: [SAR command in X86 assembly with one parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12813962) - took me a while to find, had to google `site:stackoverflow.com x86 shift implicit count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, NASM requires the count even if it's 1. Inspection of the generated machine code reveals that `shl di` and `shl di, 1` indeed generate the same opcodes.